# GitHub: How to set headers for ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, github

How do I set authorization headers for ajax request to make request on GitHub account?

I have created [**Personal Access Tokens**](https://github.com/settings/applications) on GitHub to use it with ajax for authentication to perform operations on my repository.

ajax request is made as shown below:

```
var apiDomain = 'https://api.github.com',
    api="/users/" + username;
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "token 8da3512a16c3fc0d33d8932ca37e6f5bc4c695c0");
        },
        url:apiDomain+api+'?callback=testUser',
        dataType:'script'
    });
```

I get the response data as expected. However, the ajax call is unauthenticated and I always see the following on the `meta` object

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: "60"
X-RateLimit-Remaining: "55"
X-RateLimit-Reset: "1387964695"
status: 200
```

If the ajax request is authenticated I should be able to make ~5000 requests.

How do I use my **Personal Access Tokens** to make more ajax requests on GitHub?

Comment: Would https://gist.github.com/STRd6/6286182/#file-gistquire-coffee and https://gist.github.com/STRd6/6286182/#file-github-js be of any help?

Comment: Thanks @VonC. That did help in a way. I simply passed my ?access_token=<token> to api.github.com as a query parameter and it helped me get authorized :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing the access_token as a query parameter solved the problem.

Here is the modified version with the query parameter "access_token"

```
var apiDomain = 'https://api.github.com',
    api="/users/" + username;
    $.ajax({
        url:apiDomain+api+'?callback=testUser&access_token=8da3512a16c3fc0d33d8932ca37e6f5bc4c695c0',
        dataType:'script'
    });
```

P.S: The comment in the question helped me find the solution. Thanks [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771079/github-how-to-set-headers-for-ajax-request?noredirect=1#comment31132941_20771079)